# How to show/hide certain fields (ex: status=false)in a table using checkbox in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to show and hide all the field in a table which are having **status= false**. when I check the checkbox, all the records including status=false should show. when I uncheck the checkbox it should hide all the records with status=false.
could some one help me how to do it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-request-in-angular-6-pffwgg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: what did you try so far? what framework are you using (`angular` or `angularjs`)? what problem did you run into? Please take a look how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to use a function for returning the filtered data. Performance will be slightly reduced, but there are a lot of ways to mitigate that. I updated your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-request-in-angular-6-gw57i8?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
<tr *ngFor="let datas of displayData()">
```

I set the checked-value from the checkbox to a boolean (onlyActive), so this could be used for filtering.

```
displayData(): any[] {
    return this.httpData?.filter(x => x.completed !== this.onlyActive )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

there's a number of ways I can think of.

First step would be to actually define the attribute you want to filter on in your interface:

```
interface Kafein {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  completed: string;
}
```

That will let you access the property in your .ts and .html file, and it's good practice in either case.

Second step is to read the event value from the checkbox, so you can do active filtering. You can do that either by passing the event to the typescript code, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="showIncative($event)">
```

... or define a [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and read the value inside the function every time you call it, but personally I prefer passing the event.

Advantage: The table's data will change, which will cause the binding to trigger and the view to update.

Alternatively, you could bind the value of checkbox directly to a public instance variable.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="displayInactiveItems">
```

Disadvantage: The binding will not be triggered, which means that you have to call some function to trigger the HTML's update.

Working example:

HTML:

```
<p>Http Request</p>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" (click)="showIncative($event)">
  <label>show inactive/false</label>
</div>
<table width="100%" class="my-table">
  <thead class="my-table headers">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>User Id</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="my-table body">
    <tr *ngFor="let datas of filterInactive(httpData)">
      <td>{{datas.id}}</td>
      <td style="padding-left:50px">{{datas.title}}</td>
      <td>{{datas.userId}}</td>
      <td>{{datas.completed}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';

  displayData: Kafein[] = [];

  private displayInactive: boolean = false;

  public showIncative(event: {target: {checked: boolean}}) {
    this.displayInactive = event.target.checked;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<Kafein[]>(this.url).subscribe(data => {
      this.displayData = data;
    });
  }

  public filterInactive(items: Kafein[] = this.displayData) {
    return this.displayInactive
      ? items
      : items.filter(item => /true/i.test(item.completed));
  }
}
```

Another way would be to bind the data from the request to one variable, and the data you actually display to another (I just saw the crosspost):

Typescript:

```
  requestData: Kafein[] = [];
  displayData: Kafein[] = [];

  public showIncative(event?) {
    if (event && event.target.checked) {
      this.displayData = this.requestData; 
    } else {
      this.displayData = this.requestData.filter(item => /true/i.test(item.completed));
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<Kafein[]>(this.url).subscribe(data => {
      this.requestData = data;
      this.showIncative();
    });
  }
```

Plenty of ways to skin that particular cat!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did certain modification in you `app.component.ts`, refer below
**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
  httpData: any;
  // different display variable created
  displayData: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<Kafein[]>(this.url).subscribe(data => {
      this.httpData = data;
      // keeping a local copy of response
      this.displayData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.httpData));
    });
  }
  showIncative(value) {
    // based on checked/unchecked flag you can filter data
    this.displayData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.httpData.filter(f => f.completed == value.currentTarget.checked)));
  }
}
```

and in `app.component.html`
**app.component.html**

```
<p>Http Request</p>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="showIncative($event)">
  <label>show inactive/false</label>
</div>
<table width="100%" class="my-table">
  <thead class="my-table headers">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>User Id</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="my-table body">
    <tr *ngFor="let datas of displayData">
      <td>{{datas.id}}</td>
      <td style="padding-left:50px">{{datas.title}}</td>
      <td>{{datas.userId}}</td>
      <td>{{datas.completed}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-request-in-angular-6-t25fcy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)